# How to disable replace with "?->" suggestions?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, autosuggest

I am not entirely sure what to even google for (I tried few things without luck).

No option on the popup to disable that particular suggestion - anyone know how to do this?

[image]

When I click "More Actions", I get following:
[image]

Nowhere in any of these is there an option to Disable this type of suggestion (?)

When I click the hamburger I get following:
[image]

But I don't want to disable ALL quick fixes (not clear whether selecting this disable just this one - which is what I want - one or all ...)

PhpStorm version: 2023.3.2
Mac OS Ventura

Comment: They are, behind the "More Actions..." click. Do this: 1) Click on `More Actions...` or invoke that shortcut (it's `Alt+Enter` here on Windows in most keymaps) 2) It will bring the Quick Fix / Intentions menu. 3) Select the most appropriate entry (almost always it will be the top one) 4) Expand the submenu (either using a mouse or just use `Arrow Right` key

Comment: 5) It will give you the list with actions. Either select `Disable inspection` or choose the top most one: `Edit inspection profile settings` that will take you to the corresponding inspection which you can disable or configure as needed (e.g. lower the severity and therefore the highlighting while still be able to apply the change if needed). The bonus: you will know which inspection is that, what options it has etc.

Comment: thanks @LazyOne can't seem to see that option anywhere (see edit added)

Comment: Do the step #4 -- either click on ">" or use the keyboard (easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No option on the popup to disable that particular suggestion - anyone know how to do this?

It is there, behind the "More Actions..."

1. Either click on `More Actions...` or invoke it via the shortcut (it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> here on Windows in most keymaps).
2. It will bring the Quick Fix / Intentions menu.

   [image]
3. Select the most appropriate entry (virtually always, it will be the top one)
4. Expand the submenu (either using a mouse or just use the keyboard - it's easier, just hit the <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> key):

   [image]
5. It will give you an extra menu with actions. Either select `Disable inspection` right away or choose the top most one: `Edit inspection profile settings`.

   [image]

The latter will take you to the corresponding inspection, which you can then disable or configure as needed (e.g. lower the severity or how it is  highlighted in the editor, while still keep the ability to apply the suggested change in other similar places if needed). As the bonus you will now know which inspection is that/where to find it, what options it has, etc.

[image]

Comment: Haha I feel like a proper noob now (just needed a little keyboard right arrow action there), thanks so much @LazyOne, that worked!